# Delay time in GMS2

Tags: game-maker, gml, game-maker-studio-2

I am trying to make it so that when you click it will show a different `cursor_sprite` for 0.25 seconds. I currently need some way to add a delay to this. Here is my code so far:

In create event:

```
/// @description Set cursor
cursor_sprite = spr_cursor;
```

In step event:

```
/// @description If click change cursor

if mouse_check_button_pressed(mb_left)
{
    cursor_sprite = spr_cursor2;
    // I want to add the delay here.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the build-in [Alarms](https://manual.yoyogames.com/#t=GameMaker_Language%2FGML_Reference%2FAsset_Management%2FInstances%2FInstance_Variables%2Falarm.htm&rhsearch=alarm&rhhlterm=alarm) for this, but I don't like these much when it becomes nested with parent objects.

So instead of Alarms, this is the way I would do it:

Create Event:

```
cursor_sprite = spr_cursor;
timer = 0;
timermax = 0.25;
```

I create 2 variables: the `timer` will be used to count down, and the `timermax` to reset it's time.

Step Event:

```
if (timer > 0)
{
    timer -= 1/room_speed //decrease in seconds
}
else
{
    cursor_sprite = spr_cursor;
}

if mouse_check_button_pressed(mb_left)
{
    cursor_sprite = spr_cursor2;
    timer = timermax;
}
```

For each timer, I let it count down in the Step Event through `1/room_speed`, that way, it will decrease the value in real-time seconds.

Then you can set the timer through `timer = timermax`

Then if the timer reaches zero, it'll do the given action afterwards.

Though a reminder that it's in the Step Event, so once the timer reaches zero, it'll always reach the `else` statement if there are no other conditions before. Usually I use the else-statement to change conditions so it doesn't reach the timer code multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

@Steven:
This is useful as far as it goes, but I think you mixed up the starting values for `timer` and `timermax`. If `timer` is counting *down*, then it obviously can't start at 0.

Also, starting `timer` at your intended duration completely obviates the need for even having a second variable (`timermax`).

So it could go:

Create Event:

```
cursor_sprite = spr_cursor;
timer = 0.25;
```

Step Event:

```
if mouse_check_button_pressed(mb_left)
{
    cursor_sprite = spr_cursor2;
    timer = 0.25;
}

if (timer > 0)
{
    timer -= 1/room_speed //decrease in seconds
}
else
{
    cursor_sprite = spr_cursor;
}
```